# downloading zip files from url using perl

Tags: perl

I have a URL, when that URL is requested, it starts the downloading a .zip file. The Zip contains the PDF file.

I have tried with WWW::Mechanize, zip file getting generated but when try to open the PDF file, it gives me error like "Not a supported file type or file has been damaged"

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$URL = "http:....";
my $filename = "test.zip";
$mech->get($URL,":content_file" => "$filename",);
```

Help me in this.

Comment: Are you trying to unzip the ZIP-file?

Comment: @Zaid - i am trying to download the zip files into the local directory

Answer (score 3):

You can do `$mech->get($url)` to get an url, and then receive raw content with `content` method:

```
printf "ct=%s len=%d\n", $mech->ct(), length($mech->content(raw => 1));
```

Later you can use this buffer to uncompress your zip, for example:

```
my $z = new IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress(\$mech->content(raw => 1)) or die "Cant uncompress: $@ $!";
```

Comment: I am trying to download the zip file(from the url) into the local directory.By using my code, I can able to download the zip file(from the url) into the local directory. When uncompressing that manually, not able to open the PDF file.

Comment: @Swaiya surely, you can write content to disk instead decompressing

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working. `$mech->ct` is "application/zip". So saved the file content with .zip format. Now I can able to download the zip into the local directory and after downloading, manually I can uncompress/view the content in the zip file without any error.

`$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$URL="http://www......";
$mech->get($URL);
$mech->save_content("test.zip");`

Thanks for the help.